# Remove filename section in command bar in neovim

Tags: neovim

[image]

I have a lualine plugin which also displays a filename section, so essentially i don't need the default one which is on the right, how do i disable it, i tried setting `vim.opt.statusline = ""` but this didn't work...

Comment: I'd start looking at https://github.com/nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim?tab=readme-ov-file#default-configuration

Comment: I suspect that you are using a plugin to set your status line (e.g. [lualine](https://github.com/nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim), [lightline](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim) ...) or maybe are you using a Neovim "distribution" like [NvChad](https://nvchad.com/) or [LazyVim](https://github.com/LazyVim/LazyVim). The answer depends on this. Could you gives more indication about this?

Comment: This is not a distro, i'm building one myself, and yes i use lualine as my plugin for the command bar

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt .

Comment: Anyways, fixed this one, thx y'all